# getAttribute function not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare a custom attribute of a given element to that custom attribute of all other elements with a specific class... here is what I have

```
function choose(el){
    var text = $(el).getAttribute("data-custom");
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length ; i++) {
        if (list[i].getAttribute("data-custom") == text) {
            /*DO STUFF*/
        }
    }
}
```

html

```
<div onclick="choose(this)">STUFF</div>
```

Currently I get a "$(...).getAttribute is not a function" error.

Comment: the function is `attr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery version is [`$().attr('data-custom')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Note that to access `data-*` attributes, you can use [`$().data('custom')`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Or you could ditch jQuery (you didn't use it in the very next line) and use

```
el.getAttribute('data-custom');
// If el is not a DOM element
$(el)[0].getAttribute('data-custom');
```

Even better, if you don't have to support IE < 11, you can use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

```
el.dataset.custom
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing javascript and jquery.

```
$(...).attr('your_attr')
```